# html-conduit (HTML -> XHTML in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, xml-conduit

I am a beginner to Haskell.
I have some code that uses xml-conduit, and it's all working well, I am able to transform it as I want.

```
let src_file = "blah.xhtml"
Document prologue root epilogue <- readFile def{psDecodeEntities=decodeHtmlEntities} src_file

let root' = transform root

-- And now we write out. Let's indent our output
writeFile def
    { rsPretty = True
    } "output.xhtml" $ Document prologue root' epilogue
```

The problem I have is that my input comes from html (from the web). I want to feed this into my function. Currently to do this, I have to run the commandline utility 'tidy' to normalise it to XHTML:

```
tidy -output blah.xhtml -asxhtml blah.html
```

This is working but is not obviously not ideal. I don't want to write a commandline wrapper around 'tidy' and I am sure that this must have been solved already! I have found the html-conduit package, but couldn't work out how to connect one to the other. 
If someone could shed some light about how to go about this, or another library that would do what I want, I would be grateful. I tried reading the documentation for html-conduit but couldn't work out how the two libraries interoperate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the readFile function from html-conduit. What problems have you run into when trying to integrate the two libraries?

Comment: That solved it - (I was getting caught out by something else when I tried before!) I am continuously amazed by how nicely things in Haskell fit together!!